# C# - If user refreshes page after inserting a record, a duplicate record is created. How can I prevent this?

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, insert, postback

This is true with any other functionality present on the page. I don't want the last event that happened before post back to happen again.

Comment: for a more specific answer you'll need to provide code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should take a look at the [PRG Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (Post/Redirect/Get)

> Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) is a common design pattern for web developers
>   to help avoid certain duplicate form submissions and allow user agents
>   to behave more intuitively with bookmarks and the refresh button

In ASP.NET:

1. POST - Submit button click causes HTTP POST
2. REDIRECT + GET - [HttpResponse.Redirect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirect.aspx)

MSDN, [Redirecting Users to Another Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3x8t37x.aspx)

> In server code, you can programmatically redirect by calling the
>   Redirect method. The method sends a command to the user's browser that
>   causes the browser to issue an HTTP GET command for the target page.

Few important notes regarding PRG pattern:

> **!!!** The PRG pattern cannot address every scenario of duplicate form
>   submission. Some known duplicate form submissions that PRG cannot
>   solve are:
>
> - if a web user goes back to the web form and resubmits it.
> - if a web user clicks a submission button multiple times before the server response loads (may be prevented by using JavaScript to disable
>     the button after the first click).
> - if a web user refreshes before the initial submission has completed because of server lag, resulting in a duplicate HTTP POST request in
>     certain user agents.
> - if a malicious web user submits the form twice despite client-side safeguards and typical browser behavior.

Comment: Nonce keys however, work all the time for solving about PRG-NOT-WORKING-SENARIOS. The nonce key is a random unique GUID generated by the server (also saved in the database) and embedded in the form. When the user POSTs the form, the nonce key also gets posted. As soon as a POST comes in to the server, the server verifies the nonce key exists in its database. If it does, the server deletes the key from the database and processes the form. Consequently if the user POSTs twice, the second POST won't be processed because the nonce key was deleted after processing the first POST.

Answer (score 3):

You should learn about the PRG (Post/Redirect/Get) pattern:

> Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) is a common design pattern for web developers
>   to help avoid certain duplicate form submissions and allow user agents
>   to behave more intuitively with bookmarks and the refresh button.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Basically you'll want to redirect via a GET request after the user has done a POST.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. So from what I can tell, in the context of .Net webforms, the only way to achieve this is to implement something like Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl) after each action I don;'t want repeated... Causing two rountrips to the server :( It sucks! But I HAVE to do it I suppose...

Comment: @Kronprinz : yep you are right, in my answer you can find a link to the MSDN page which precisely describes this point

Answer (score 2):

you can check already exist condition before inserting record in Database.

like  in stored procedure you can check

if not exists (select id from table where column name ='test' )
begin
  inser statement..
end

Comment: I don;t have access to the database, I'm working via SOAP calls.

Comment: then you can set flag value in view state like at first time when isnerted then set viewstate["isinserted"] = true and then check condition like only insert when  viewstate["isinserted"]= false

Answer (score 1):

This is about [PRG](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/Post-Redirect-Get.aspx). The simple way to avoid this is redirect user to same page again:

**Page:** `Update.aspx`

```
void btnUpdate_click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    // do your update here
    Response.Redirect("Update.aspx");
}
```

This will create a `redirect-header` in `Resoinse` and browser will create a `GET` request to `Update.aspx` page. And if the User refresh the page, a `GET` will be sent. Look:

1. User submit the form : **POST**
2. Server do updates, return a redirect-header
3. Browser receives the `response` as a redirect-command : **REDIRECT**
4. Browser sends a `GET` request for same page to server : **GET**
5. Browser receives the `response` answered by a `GET`
6. If user refreshes the page: Browsers last command was `GET`, so will not fires a `submit` again

Comment: Two rountrips to server :( 

I wish there was a better solution. This should be built into the framework somehow :)

Comment: In PRG, you have a `POST` a `REDIRECT` and a `GET` that means you have to request to server 2 times! Also you can search for another pattern to avoiding rountrips :D

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use javascript to disable the button when the users click it.

A way I use to avoid refreshes when high security is needed, is the use of a small "token" in session.
Let's say, we put a small 32 bit integer in our session.

The page will contain an hidden input containing our small integer token.
Each time we receive the page request, we increment that token by one, and, before doing so, we check for equality with the one received in the request.

If they match, it is not a refresh.
If they don't match, it is a refresh.

This will also block attempt to do back and next with browser buttons.

Of course at the point that token don't matches, the page should change or you'll have again the refresh problem.
It should show something like "hey, refresh back or next not allowed, press here to continue".

For increased security, you can xor that integer with a costant value dependant for example on some other value that is constant in session.